# how to apply styles to particular Ionic components without overriding the others

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I have the range component (below). And I want to style it such that its bar's height was 50px and had gradient color.

I found in the docs how to do that via theme\variables.scss (I modify this var here: $range-ios-bar-height & $range-ios-bar-background-color), but then all of my range components will get the change of style, but I need it only for a particular instance of range element.

How can I apply these changes only to a particular ion-range?

```
<ion-range min="0" max="100" snaps=false pin="true" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="colorSlider">
    <ion-icon range-left small name="palette"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon range-right name="palette"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

Comment: I found these classes: .range-ios .range-bar in some source files and tried to play with these via .range-ios .range-bar {height: 20px;}. So it does apply change but again to all of the ranges...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a **class** attribute to the element so that you only change the style with the same class name.

```
<ion-range class="customize" min="0" max="100" snaps=false pin="true" color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="colorSlider">
    <ion-icon range-left small name="palette"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon range-right name="palette"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

And then in variable.scss(or the corresponding scss file):

```
ion-range{
   &.customize{
      height: 20px; 
   }
}
```

Therefore, only the ion-range with class customize will have height: 20px, for others are using default height.

You **cannot** override variables in sass for **only** one component, as it against the point of the sass variables, which meant to be global settings.

Comment: unfortunately this does't have an effect in Ionic. the moment I add anyting inside the brackets, there is no effect;(

Comment: basically the effect is there but for general "height" of the element and not for the bar

Comment: actually I managed to achieve what I wanted through this: .paletteSlider {
        .range-bar {
            height: 20px;
        }
    } so your advice DID work!